# Geomtric Realization as Colimit

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

So we know that geometric realization of simplicial set $X$ is just colimit of this functor F as seen here: [Notation for Geometric realization of simplicial sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994931/notation-for-geometric-realization-of-simplicial-sets).

And we can also state the geometric realization as some quotient topology, as seen below.

[image]

Since the geometric realization is the colimit, this means that we should be able to find a colimit cone

$\alpha \colon F \rightarrow \left|X\right|$. But what is this colimit cone $\alpha$ explicitly?

That is, how is $\alpha_{\sigma\colon \triangle^n \rightarrow X} \colon \left|\triangle^n\right| \rightarrow \left|X\right|$ defined as a function, where $\left|X\right|$ is given by definition 7 in the image?

Thanks!

Comment: You use $X$ and $X_*$ for the same thing, which may be confusing. Moreover you should explicitly describe the functor $F$ to keep you question self-contained. Do not expect that readers do all this work for you.

Comment: I assume you know the Yoneda lemma: each simplicial set morphism $\Delta^n \to X$ corresponds to an element of $X_n$. There are $X_n$ copies of $| \Delta^n |$ before taking the quotient. The map you want is the obvious one: identity on $| \Delta^n |$, mapping into the copy corresponding to the node of the colimit diagram.