# Confusion in the definition of geometric realization of a simplicial set as a colimit.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

In the answer given by **@Kevin Arlin** in the **MSE** question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2994934/820022 **if I am not mistaken** the *geometric realization of a simplicial set $X$ is defined as a colimit of the following diagram in **Top*** :

$\pi \circ p:\Delta \downarrow X \rightarrow Top$ where $\pi:\Delta \rightarrow Top$ is defined as the canonical functor sending $[n] \rightarrow |\Delta^n|$ in object level (where $|\Delta^n|$ is the standard geometric $n$-simpplex) and also appropriately defined in the morphism level whereas I guess $p:\Delta \downarrow X \rightarrow \Delta$ is defined as follows:

**On Objects:** $(\sigma:\Delta^n \rightarrow X) \mapsto [n] \in \Delta,$ the usual **finite ordinal category.**

**On Morphisms:** [image] $\theta \mapsto (\theta_{*}:[n] \rightarrow [m])$

where $\theta_{*}:[n] \rightarrow [m]$ is defined as $\theta_{[n]}(1_{[n]})$ (Coming from *contravariant Yoneda lemma*).

**I was trying to show that $p$ is indeed a functor but I am struck at the following step** while showing $(\psi \circ \phi)_{*}= \psi_{*} \circ \phi_{*}$ where $\psi:\Delta^m \rightarrow \Delta^{r}$ and $\phi: \Delta^{n} \rightarrow \Delta^{m}$. *(Though I made abuse of notation for convenience*).

**My confusion:**

$\psi_{*} \circ \phi_{*}= \psi_{[m]}(1_{[m]}) \circ \phi_{[n]}(1_{[n]})$......**(1)**

$(\psi \circ \phi)_{*}=(\psi \circ \phi)_{[n]}(1_{[n]})= \psi_{[n]} \circ \phi_{[n]}(1_{[n]})$.....**(2)**

*I am not able to show* **(1)** = **(2)**.

**Am I misunderstanding anything?**

*Or did I interpret the answer by* **@Kevin Arlin** *in an incorrect way?*

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: My question is more appropriate as a comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2994934/820022 but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on that answer. I apologise in advance for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: What does the Yoneda lemma tell you about where $\psi$ sends $\phi(1_{[n]})$? Also your question might also be phrased as "Why is the Yoneda embedding functorial"?

Comment: @jgon Thanks for the reply. But Yoneda embedding is in the other direction i.e $Y: \Delta \rightarrow sSets$. I can show that $Y$ is functorial. But I could not show functoriality in the opposite  direction which is probably equivalent to the solution of my question.

Comment: Sure, but the Yoneda embedding is an embedding, so it being functorial means the inverse is functorial as well.

Comment: @jgon Yh.. I am trying to understand. Thanks.. But embedding means it has "weak inverse" but not exact inverse.

Comment: @jgon Thanks I got it

Comment: Sorry, I've been being brief, since I'm on mobile. What I mean is that if $F$ is a faithful functor, and $F(f)F(g)=F(h)$, then $F(fg)=F(h)$, so $h=fg$ by faithfulness. We don't need the full strength of an embedding for this result, or an inverse equivalence. In our case we know that the original maps are the Yoneda embedding applied to the starred versions.

Comment: Glad to see you worked it out.

Comment: @jgon Thank you very much.

Comment: @jgon I posted an answer to this question based on my understanding after the small discussion with you. Please let me know if my argument is correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y:\Delta \rightarrow sSets$ be the **Yoneda embedding**. By Yoneda embedding there exist $g:[m] \rightarrow  [r]$ and $f:[n] \rightarrow [m]$ such that $\psi = Y(g)$ and $\phi= Y(f)$.

So $\psi \circ \phi=Y(g) \circ Y(f)$.

Now component wise, $(\psi \circ \phi)_{[k]}= \psi_{[k]} \circ \phi_{[k]}= Y(g)_{[k]} \circ Y(f)_{[k]}$ for $[k] \in \Delta$.

So, in particular $\psi_{[m]}(1_{[m]}) \circ \phi_{[n]}(1_{[n]})=Y(g)_{[m]}(1_{[m]}) \circ Y(f)_{[n]}(1_{[n]})= g \circ 1_{[m]} \circ f \circ 1_{[n]}=g \circ f= \psi_{*} \circ \phi_{*}$ (using the same notation as mentioned in the question.)

On the other hand, $(\psi \circ \phi)_{*}= (\psi \circ \phi)_{[n]}(1_{[n]})= (Y(g) \circ Y(f))_{[n]}(1_{[n]})=Y(g \circ f)_{[n]}(1_{[n]})= g \circ f \circ 1_{[n]}= g \circ f$.

Hence $\psi_{*} \circ \phi_{*}= (\psi \circ \phi)_{*}$.

So, $p:\Delta \downarrow X \rightarrow \Delta$ is a functor. **(Proved)**

(Indentity Preservation is easy to show.)

Comment: Yeah that works, although the Yoneda lemma also says that $\psi=Y(\psi_*)$, so you don't really need to introduce new morphisms $f$ and $g$. However, this argument is correct.

Comment: @jgon Thank you I got your point.